# How to pass javascript values from index.html to child component in Angular4

Tags: angular

I have a script in index.html and I want to pass the output of that script to my child component .
In my case the child component name is my-cart ,Want to pass the data from index.html to my-cart-component.ts file .

**index.html file and Child component code**

```js
import { Component,EventEmitter,Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SessionStorageService,SessionStorage } from 'angular-web-storage';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-cart',
  templateUrl: './my-cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-cart.component.css'],
  outputs :['ChildEvent']
})

export class MyCartComponent  {
 constructor(private router:Router,private http: HttpClient) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(
      () => window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h2>Local IP</h2>


    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function getIPs(callback){
    var ip_dups = {};
    var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
        || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
        || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    if(!RTCPeerConnection){
        var win = iframe.contentWindow;
        RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
            || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
            || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
        useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    }
    var mediaConstraints = {
        optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
    };
    var servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};
    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);
    function handleCandidate(candidate){
        var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
        var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];
        if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
            callback(ip_addr);
        ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
    }
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){
        if(ice.candidate)
        handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
    };
    pc.createDataChannel("");
    pc.createOffer(function(result){
        pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});
    }, function(){});
  
    setTimeout(function(){

        var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');
        lines.forEach(function(line){
        if(line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
           handleCandidate(line);
        });
    }, 1000);
}

getIPs(function(ip){document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ip;});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone can guide me to solve this problem...

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just put your script into your child ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can create some_property on **window** global object and access it anywhere:

   [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sshbb3?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)
2. Access element value by **document** object:

   (document.getElementById('demo')).value;

   [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwb9pd?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

But in this cases there is no guarantee that the script result finished proceeding before angular component initialization process, which means components doesn't know when script result will be ready

Comment: @Nikson, you want to take local ip? 10.1.2.3

Comment: Update your getIPs method. getIPs(function(ip){document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ip; **window['script_result'] = ip;**
});

Comment: I want to assign the local ip to 

window['script_result'] = 'IP'

Comment: for my case I can't get the IP from this method 

getIPs(function(ip){document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ip;});

Like your example code...I couldn't access my IP out of that method

Comment: @Nikson, I only can say accessing to script result from angular component is not good practice. Because angular components doesn't know when your script result will be ready.